# Cannot locate option dropdown with value in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("LOGON_selectedUser")));
   
   WebElement mySelectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("LOGON_selectedUser"));
   
   mySelectElement.click();
   
   
     Select dropdown= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("LOGON_selectedUser")));
  
     dropdown.selectByVisibleText("HOTLINE-FAMILY SAFETY - Acting Supervisor");
```

Below is the error I'm getting:

Cannot locate option with text: HOTLINE-FAMILY SAFETY - Acting Supervisor
I tried with by. value bit no luck. :(

However, I'm able to select the dropdown with statement      mySelectElement.click(); but when I try to select the drop-down, I'm keep on getting cannot locate the element. Pls help.

Here is the DOM:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsxWC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web page has been built using Angular. Please try to induce `Explicit waits` with `Select class`.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@name='selectedUser' and @id='LOGON_selectedUser' and @onchange]"))));
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

or if that does not work, the below should work

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('LOGON_selectedUser').selectedIndex = '" + index + "';)
```

where `index`  is a variable, try to pass index number like 1,2,3 and so on...

Comment: Thanks the below code worked:       ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('LOGON_selectedUser').selectedIndex = '1' " );